# jQuery append() - return appended elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add some elements dynamically. Is there any way to get a jQuery collection or array of these newly inserted elements?

So I want to do this:

```
$("#myDiv").append(newHtml);
var newElementsAppended = // answer to the question I'm asking
newElementsAppended.effects("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to get a jQuery object from appended element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443233/easier-way-to-get-a-jquery-object-from-appended-element)

Answer (score 274, accepted):

There's a simpler way to do this:

```
$(newHtml).appendTo('#myDiv').effects(...);
```

This turns things around by first creating `newHtml` with [`jQuery(html [, ownerDocument ])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), and then using [`appendTo(target)`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) (note the "`To`" bit) to add that it to the end of `#mydiv`.

Because you now *start* with `$(newHtml)` the end result of `appendTo('#myDiv')` is that new bit of html, and the `.effects(...)` call will be on that *new* bit of html too.

Comment: Using jQuery UI version 1.9.2 I'm getting `effects` is not a function... but `effect`is

Comment: I would add that there is also another signature: appendTo(target, context). Such as for any jQuery selector it allows to search for target , BUT only inside a specific context. It can be very useful if you write plugins or libraries.

Comment: This will throw an error if `newHtml` is not valid HTML or a valid jQuery selector: `$('/ This is Not HTML /').appendTo('#myDiv')` results in `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` while `$('#myDiv').append('/ This is Not HTML /')` works properly by appending text to the target element.

Answer (score 47):

```
// wrap it in jQuery, now it's a collection
var $elements = $(someHTML);

// append to the DOM
$("#myDiv").append($elements);

// do stuff, using the initial reference
$elements.effects("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Comment: This did not work for me when I later tried to bind an event to the appended element. I used var appendedTarget = $(newHtml).appendTo(element). I could then bind using $(appendedTarget).bind('keydown',someFunc)

Comment: I think it is `$elements.effect("highlight", {}, 2000);`, not `effects`.

Comment: This doesnt work because the $elements variable after being appended, changes and is no longer available.

Comment: @AlexV This seems to work, see live demo on http://jsbin.com/xivedohofi/1/edit?html,js,output , also see the same answer as accepted for the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443233/easier-way-to-get-a-jquery-object-from-appended-element

Comment: It appears they have fixed this in newer versions of the jQuery.

Answer (score 33):

```
var newElementsAppended = $(newHtml).appendTo("#myDiv");
newElementsAppended.effects("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 10):

**A little reminder**, when elements are added dynamically, functions like `append()`, `appendTo()`, `prepend()` or `prependTo()` return a jQuery object, not the HTML DOM element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6hFZ/1/)

```
var container=$("div.container").get(0),
    htmlA="<div class=children>A</div>",
    htmlB="<div class=children>B</div>";

// jQuery object
alert( $(container).append(htmlA) ); // outputs "[object Object]"

// HTML DOM element
alert( $(container).append(htmlB).get(0) ); // outputs "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

Comment: The returned element from append() is the container and not the new element.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something like this:

```
var $child = $("#parentId").append("<div></div>").children("div:last-child");
```

The parent #parentId is returned from the append, so add a jquery children query to it to get the last div child inserted.

$child is then the jquery wrapped child div that was added.