# jQuery: how to return the appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery API `append()` to add a new element:

`$(selector).append('<div class="test"></div>')`

I want the expression return the just appended element for my further use, however it returns `$(selector)`. So, how can I let jQuery to return the just appended element to avoid re-selecting it?

Comment: `$('<div class="test"></div>').appendTo(selector)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery append() - return appended elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159368/jquery-append-return-appended-elements) -- what happend to searching first? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the way to do that would be to use `appendTo()`

Then you could do

```
$('<div class="test"></div>').appendTo(selector).css('background','blue');
```

or whatever you wanted to do.

That would cause the `div` you just appended to have a blue background.

Answer (score 4):

You can just store a reference to it. Keep in mind that you should do all your manipulations with `$div` before appending it to an element that is part of the `DOM` to avoid multiple reflows.

```
var $div = $('<div class="test"></div>');

$(selector).append($div);
```

Comment: You don't need the $ before the div var

Comment: @BillyMathews, that is common for jquery object vars

Comment: @BillyMathews It's a naming convention widely used to identity variables that hold references to jQuery objects.

Comment: @BillyMathews what is the difference between this answer and mine?

Comment: @Jamie: Here, `$div` is a jQuery object. In your answer `markup` is a string. Even if you pass it to jQuery again it will create a different DOM element for the same markup. So, the key is to keep a reference to the DOM element, not the HTML string.

Comment: the OP didn't ask for anything like this though :/ and everything in js is referenced. So it wouldn't create a new DOM element. IMO

Comment: @JamieHutber, "how can I let jQuery to return the just appended element to avoid re-selecting it" In other words, "how can I keep a reference to the element that was added". This is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @Jamie: You asked for the difference of the answers, I'm not judging (well, in fact I do, this question is a duplicate and you should all vote to close it). And no, parsing the same HTML string twice will create different DOM elements.

Comment: argh... well why didn't heee say that :p but ye, make sense. Still think peoples responses were wrong and ill informed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the element independently from `append` by passing the html string to the [`jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

```
$('<div class="test"></div>');
```

You can use that either in the [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(selector).append(/* $div = */$('<div class="test"></div>').… );
```

or with [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
/* $div = */$('<div class="test"></div>').appendTo(selector).… ;
```

or you just separate them into two statements.

Answer (score 0):

This can work too.

```
<div class="inner">hellworld</div>
$('.inner').append('<p>paragraph</p>');
```

this will insert two new s and an existing  as the last three child nodes of the body

```
var $newdiv1 = $('<div id="object1"/>'),
newdiv2 = document.createElement('div'),
existingdiv1 = document.getElementById('foo');
$('body').append($newdiv1, [newdiv2, existingdiv1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$(selector).append('<div class="test"></div>').find('div.test:last-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return it by add `childern` jQuery function as in this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/PpHLj/)

```
$(selector).append('<div class="test"></div>').children('.test');
```

or you can use `prependTO` jQuery function as in this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/PpHLj/1/) :

```
$('<div class="test"></div>').prependTo(selector);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try either

```
var elt = $('<div class="test"></div>');
$(selector).append(elt);
```

Or using appendTo instead of append, and then chain whatever you need (*show()* in the example below)

```
$('<div class="test"></div>').appendTo($(selector)).show()
```

Comment: Still don't understand why same solutions as the selected one are downvoted... we don't all have a good connection, and sometimes it's (incorrectly) can be considered as duplicate because of posting time, but its explanations can be helpful for those who need examples...