# jQuery - Passing an object to the click handler

Tags: jquery

```
for(let feature of features){
   $("#menuList").append("<li></li>");
}
$("#menuList li").on('click', function(ev){ 
  // I need a reference to the original feature object here 
});
```

What is the best way to get a reference to the original feature-object within the click handler (without passing some ID as a data tag and iterating over the list again)?

Ideally, I could do something like

```
for(let feature of features){
   $("#menuList").append("<li></li>").on('click', function(feature){ //do something with the feature object });
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Did you try using $(document).on('click', "#menuList li", function(ev){ ... because your element is appended

Comment: What actually is `feature` or `features` here? Are you appending anything to `li` from it?

Comment: feature is just an object. I will definitely use some of it's attributes to build the `li` but I really need to pass the object to the click handler, that's the problem

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159368/jquery-append-return-appended-elements
`$.appendTo` looks to be another function that will return a reference to the just appended element (not a ref to the parent element like `$.append()` does), and you'll be able to set that `.on('click'` directly, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks artur99, this looks promising! Gonna try that.

Comment: $(this) inside the click function would be the reference to the <li> you clicked. Why are most people giving a complicated answer to it while it's really simple lol.

Comment: @SinanSamet, How can OP access `feature` object? `$(this)` is not a magic want will solve all problem. Seems you didn't understood the problem

Answer (score 3):

Since you are adding the `li elements` dynamically, you need to perform `event delegation` i.e. attaching click event on existing element, say `#menuList` here and through it navigate to clicked `li` and with `$(this)` you can get reference to clicked element through which you can get its `index` and get your original object from `features` as below:

```
$("#menuList").on('click','li', function(ev){ 
  var currentIndex=$(this).index();
  var feature=features[currentIndex]; //your required object from features object
});
```

**Assuming that `menuList` will have fresh `li` appended each time.**

Answer (score 1):

just use `$(this)`

Something like:

```js
$('#menuList').on('click', 'li', function(ev){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('xxx');
  //console.log($(this));
});
```

```css
li.xxx {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menuList">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the event raising object with `$(this)` within the handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can persist `feature` with element using [`$.fn.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which can be retrieved later in the event handler.

```js
for (let feature of features) {
  var li = $("<li></li>");
  li.data('feature', feature);
  $("#menuList").append(li);
}
$("#menuList").on('click', 'li', function(ev) {
  var feature = $(event.target).data('feature');
});
```