# How to get reference to jQuery selector for content just added via manipulation method?

Tags: jquery

If content is added to the DOM using, e.g.,

```
$("ul").append("<li>test</li>");
```

how does one get a reference the content just added w/o having to select the newly added content?

Assigning the return value from the append() method is the jQuery object.

```
var newContent=$("ul").append("<li>test</li>");
```

One could do

```
var newContent=$("ul li:last");
```

but is there a way to get it more directly?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to get a jQuery object from appended element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443233/easier-way-to-get-a-jquery-object-from-appended-element)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

> *Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target*...
>
> The [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and `.appendTo()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With `.append()`, the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With `.appendTo()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container...

Comment: Seconded... this makes for a lot less confusion.

Comment: If you use `.appendTo()` keep in mind that the order is reversed, unlike a regular `.append()` so it'd be `$("content to append").appendTo("#selector");`

Comment: Although the answer below works, this answer provides more flexibility and less code. The main reason is you can easily chain additional methods on the same line. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can create it in its own line ala:

```
var newLi = $('<li>test</li>');
$('ul').append(newLi);

//Continue using newLi and it will affect the appended element
```

Comment: The limitation of this approach is you have to create a local variable and than perform execute additional methods on it. I was hoping for a way to create the new element and "chain" methods to is all at once.