# jQuery Selector For .append'd Content

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery function to add inputs on an anchor click:

```
$("a#addrec").click(function () {
    var max = $("span#recommends input[id^='rec']:last").attr("id").substr(3, 1);                                   
    var next = max + 1;
    $("span#recommends").append('<input type="text" id="rec'+next+'" name="rec[]" placeholder="Joe\'s Nightclub" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-top: 10px;" /><div id="rec'+next+'err" class="err"></div><br style="clear: both;" />');
    return false;
});
```

and, I would like to id them sequentially, (ie. rec1, rec2, rec3, etc.) but I'm obviously doing something wrong. The input is added, but the selector to find the last input only finds the last non-appended input, rather than the last of the set of existing and appended inputs.

I've searched, and found this thread:

[How to get reference to jQuery selector for content just added via manipulation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179318/how-to-get-reference-to-jquery-selector-for-content-just-added-via-manipulation-m)

but I don't quite see how this resolves my issue.

I guess my question, in a nutshell is, "How do I select the newly appended inputs each time the anchor is clicked?"

Answer (score 1):

You have to `parseInt` (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UtA5E/)

```
$("a#addrec").click(function() {
    var max = $("span#recommends input[id^='rec']:last").attr("id").substr(3, 1);
    var next = parseInt(max) + 1;
    $("span#recommends").append('<input type="text" id="rec' + next + '" name="rec[]" placeholder="Joe\'s Nightclub" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-top: 10px;" /><div id="rec' + next + 'err" class="err"></div><br style="clear: both;" />');
    return false;
});
```

Before it was doing `'1' + 1` which is equal to `11` and then `111` etc etc.

Comment: `parseInt` will try to guess the base of the number you provide to it, but I think you are better off specifying which base you are using. So for decimal you would use `parseInt(max,10)`. It is unlikely that you will get a number starting with `0` or `0x` in this situation but it's worth noting. +1

Comment: Thank you. You're right, it does need some "massaging" of the datatypes, but I'm left with the same issue; every time the event fires, my 'max' variable is getting assigned the id of the last pre-existing ID, rather than any newly appended ones.

Answer (score 0):

Store jQuery's interpretation of the DOM element in a var and work with that instead of directly accessing the DOM each time:

```
var $records = $("span#recommends");

$("a#addrec").click(function () {
    var max = $($records + " input[id^='rec']:last").attr("id").substr(3, 1);                                   
    var next = max + 1;
    $records.append('<input type="text" id="rec'+next+'" name="rec[]" placeholder="Joe\'s Nightclub" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-top: 10px;" /><div id="rec'+next+'err" class="err"></div><br style="clear: both;" />');
    return false;
});
```