# jquery get this object of appended element

Tags: jquery

How to get the current object of the appended element

```
   var new_htm = "<div class='engagement_data'>" + htm +"</div>";
   $("#addin").append(new_htm);
```

i want to construct a this for the appended element in jquery how to do this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to get a jQuery object from appended element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443233/easier-way-to-get-a-jquery-object-from-appended-element)

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
var $new_htm = $("<div class='engagement_data'>" + htm +"</div>").appendTo("#addin");
```

`.appendTo()` returns the object that you append, whereas `append()` returns the parent object.

Comment: @raam86 Thanks for the typo fix as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Append the element and than:

```
$this  = $("#addin").find('.engagement_data');
```

An even better way can bev

`$div = $("#addin").append(newHtml).children()`

Comment: cant i say  $this = $("#addin").append(new_htm);

Comment: @Hulk, no. This results in `$this` being the parent of `new_htm`. Try it.

Comment: But will  happen to $this in case of a for loop

Comment: You can `.push` the elements into an array